# Is it possible to provide a custom pattern decomposition in Haskell?

Tags: scala, haskell, pattern-matching, type-constructor

In Haskell, I have a module with a partial order type:

```
data PartialOrder a = PartialOrder [a] [(a, a)]
```

I don't export the value constructor because that's not how I want the type to be used, but I still want to be able to pattern match the PartialOrder type outside the module; is this possible? In particular, I want to be able to pattern match something that is not the type constructor, but instead, to pattern match something like the following:

```
f (PartialOrder xs le) = ...
```

Where `le` is a function implicitly defining the explicit ordering defined in the value constructor. I know such a facility is available in Scala, is there a way to do the same in Haskell?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like a use case for `ViewPatterns`. You could write a type like:

```
data ViewPartialOrder a = ViewPartialOrder a (a -> a -> Ordering)
```

Write a function like:

```
viewOrder :: PartialOrder -> ViewPartialOrder
viewOrder (PartialOrder xs relation) = ...
```

then use the `ViewPatterns` extension to write code like this:

```
f (viewOrder -> ViewPartialOrder xs le) = ...
```

Of course, you should come up with better names for these things :P!

There's no way to have the same effect *implicitly* (ie without the `viewOrder` function), for better or worse. I think it's usually a good thing, making it clear that you're not matching the actual implementation of the type.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: The good old-fashioned "fastest gun in the west problem" :P.

Comment: The new extension PatternSynonyms will provide what you want, but it's not quite available yet.

Answer (score 3):

The suggestion to use a view pattern is a fine one, but you can get much the same effect without a view pattern by precomposing with the "view" which is, after all, just a function.

So given

```
viewOfPartialOrder :: PartialOrder -> ViewPartialOrder
viewOfPartialOrder (PartialOrder xs relation) = ...
```

as suggested by Tikhon Jelvis (under a slightly different name), instead of

```
doSomethingWithAPartialOrder :: PartialOrder a -> Whatever
doSomethingWithAPartialOrder (viewOfPartialOrder -> ViewPartialOrder xs le) = ...
```

You can define

```
doSomethingWithAView :: ViewPartialOrder a -> Whatever
doSomethingWithAView (ViewPartialOrder xs le) = ...

doSomethingWithAPartialOrder :: PartialOrder a -> Whatever
doSomethingWithAPartialOrder = doSomethingWithAView . viewOfPartialOrder
```

Personally I find it easier to edit code presented in the latter way, but you should choose whatever you personally prefer.